# How to access defined constant array in header file in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I created constant multi dimensionel array in header file. I want to access array from implementation. How to do it?

**Config.h**

```
 #define SORT_OPTIONS @[ \
        [ @3, @"Default", @"&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC" ],  \
        [ @1, @"Product Name (A - Z)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=ASC" ],  \
        [ @2, @"Product Name (Z - A)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=DESC" ], \
        [ @3, @"Low price > High price", @"&sort=p.price&order=ASC" ],  \
        [ @3, @"High price > Low price", @"&sort=p.price&order=DESC" ]]
```

**Config.m**

```
#import "Config.h"

@implementation Config

+ (void) initSortOptionsAsSortObject{
     // I want access array from here   
}

@end
```

Comment: have you tried logging it? NSLog("%@",SORT_OPTIONS)?

Comment: I actually tried it out and it works :|

Comment: Ok. How to access elements of array one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think there is something wrong with your definition.

```
#define SORT_OPTIONS @[ \
    [ @3, @"Default", @"&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC" ],  \
    [ @1, @Product Name (A - Z)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=ASC" ],  \
    [ @2, @"Product Name (Z - A)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=DESC" ], \
    [ @3, @"Low price > High price", @"&sort=p.price&order=ASC" ],  \
    [ @3, @"High price > Low price", @"&sort=p.price&order=DESC" ]]
```

the sub array does not contain `@` literal and  your `@Product Name` is missing a `"`

try it something like this:

```
#define SORT_OPTIONS @[ \
@[ @3, @"Default", @"&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC" ],  \
@[ @1, @"Product Name (A - Z)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=ASC" ],  \
@[ @2, @"Product Name (Z - A)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=DESC" ], \
@[ @3, @"Low price > High price", @"&sort=p.price&order=ASC" ],  \
@[ @3, @"High price > Low price", @"&sort=p.price&order=DESC" ]]
```

Accessing it: `SORT_OPTIONS[0]; // directly accessing the index`

Comment: It doesn't work. It gives me error like this : Expected Identifier

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see @ symbol before each element. I added it. And I accessed array as SORT_OPTIONS[0]. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try following way to access your constant array,

**In .h file after #import,**

```
#define SORT_OPTIONS @[ \
@[ @3, @"Default", @"&sort=p.sort_order&order=ASC" ],  \
@[ @1, @"Product Name (A - Z)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=ASC" ],  \
@[ @2, @"Product Name (Z - A)", @"&sort=pd.name&order=DESC" ], \
@[ @3, @"Low price > High price", @"&sort=p.price&order=ASC" ],  \
@[ @3, @"High price > Low price", @"&sort=p.price&order=DESC" ]]
```

**After in .m file,**

```
+ (void) initSortOptionsAsSortObject{
    // I want access array from here
    NSLog(@"your array - %@", SORT_OPTIONS);
}
```

**Access array elements,**

```
for (int i = 0; i < SORT_OPTIONS.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"your array - %@", [SORT_OPTIONS objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
```

**See the attached images,**

[image: .h file]

[image: .m file]

Hope It will help you.

Comment: Thank you too for your help